# electronで作成したPDFにCSSが適用されない

Tags: css, electron, angular2

electronの[WebContents.printToPdf](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsprinttopdfoptions-callback)のAPIを使って、バックグラウンドで非表示中のページをレンダリング後にPDF化したいです。

Angular2を使ってページを整形しているため、ngAfterViewInitのlifeCycleの後にPDF化を行おうとしたのですが、

PDF化したところ、一部のテキストがレンダリングされない状態でPDFが出力されてしまいました。

(electronの標準イベントであるBrowserWindowの`ready-to-show`やWebContentsの`did-finish-load`のイベントではPDF化のタイミングが早すぎる)

CSSが完全に適用されたタイミングでPDF化を行う方法はありますでしょうか？

#### 備考

システムのバージョン

```
"@angular/core": "^2.4.9",
"electron": "^1.6.16",
```

コード1

```
const newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width,
    height,
    show: false,
});
newWindow.loadURL(reportURL);
```

コード2

```
win.webContents.printToPDF({marginsType:0, pageSize:'A4', printBackground:true}, (error: any, data: any) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, function(error: any) {
        if (error) throw error;
        win.destroy();
    });
});
```

コード1を使ってバックグラウンドでBrowserWindowオブジェクトを作成し、PDFを作成するタイミングになったら、コード2を呼び出してPDF化を行なっております。